# Operating multiple gridviews with a single button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, tabpanel

Ok so i am using a AJAX tab panel with 4 tabs, each having GridViews bound to different tables. I have 1 add and 1 edit button. Is it possible to create code such that the data entered by the user in the fields is added to the tab that is selected? Is it possible? Either by if/else-if statements or switch? but i don't know what would i put the check on? Tab IDs? Here is my ASPX code..

```html
<div class="gview">
  <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="3" Width="614px">
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Cardiology" ID="TabPanel1">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" SortExpression="Designation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ward_rounds" HeaderText="Ward_rounds" SortExpression="Ward_rounds" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot1" HeaderText="Slot1" SortExpression="Slot1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot2" HeaderText="Slot2" SortExpression="Slot2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot3" HeaderText="Slot3" SortExpression="Slot3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot4" HeaderText="Slot4" SortExpression="Slot4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BreakTime" HeaderText="BreakTime" SortExpression="BreakTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot5" HeaderText="Slot5" SortExpression="Slot5" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot6" HeaderText="Slot6" SortExpression="Slot6" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot7" HeaderText="Slot7" SortExpression="Slot7" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot8" HeaderText="Slot8" SortExpression="Slot8" />
          </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:masterConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Cardio_schedule]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Neurology" ID="TabPanel2">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" SortExpression="Designation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ward_Rounds" HeaderText="Ward_Rounds" SortExpression="Ward_Rounds" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot1" HeaderText="Slot1" SortExpression="Slot1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot2" HeaderText="Slot2" SortExpression="Slot2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot3" HeaderText="Slot3" SortExpression="Slot3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot4" HeaderText="Slot4" SortExpression="Slot4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BreakTime" HeaderText="BreakTime" SortExpression="BreakTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot5" HeaderText="Slot5" SortExpression="Slot5" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot6" HeaderText="Slot6" SortExpression="Slot6" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot7" HeaderText="Slot7" SortExpression="Slot7" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot8" HeaderText="Slot8" SortExpression="Slot8" />
          </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:masterConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Neuro_schedule]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>

    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Dermatology" ID="TabPanel3">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" SortExpression="Designation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ward_Rounds" HeaderText="Ward_Rounds" SortExpression="Ward_Rounds" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot1" HeaderText="Slot1" SortExpression="Slot1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot2" HeaderText="Slot2" SortExpression="Slot2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot3" HeaderText="Slot3" SortExpression="Slot3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot4" HeaderText="Slot4" SortExpression="Slot4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BreakTime" HeaderText="BreakTime" SortExpression="BreakTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot5" HeaderText="Slot5" SortExpression="Slot5" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot6" HeaderText="Slot6" SortExpression="Slot6" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot7" HeaderText="Slot7" SortExpression="Slot7" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot8" HeaderText="Slot8" SortExpression="Slot8" />
          </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:masterConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Derma_Schedule]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Opthalmology" ID="TabPanel4">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4">
          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" SortExpression="Designation" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ward_Rounds" HeaderText="Ward_Rounds" SortExpression="Ward_Rounds" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot1" HeaderText="Slot1" SortExpression="Slot1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot2" HeaderText="Slot2" SortExpression="Slot2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot3" HeaderText="Slot3" SortExpression="Slot3" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot4" HeaderText="Slot4" SortExpression="Slot4" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BreakTime" HeaderText="BreakTime" SortExpression="BreakTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot5" HeaderText="Slot5" SortExpression="Slot5" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot6" HeaderText="Slot6" SortExpression="Slot6" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot7" HeaderText="Slot7" SortExpression="Slot7" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Slot8" HeaderText="Slot8" SortExpression="Slot8" />
          </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:masterConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Optha_schedule]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
      </ContentTemplate>

    </asp:TabPanel>

  </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>



</div>
```

I haven't put CSS code here because it's not needed. And there is no C# code yet because i need some idea on how to use 1 button to operate all 4 gridviews.

I want it to be like:

```
If (selectedTab = 1) {
    //DB code for respective table
}

else if (selectedTab= 2) {
    //DB code for respective table
}
```

and so on..

Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will work.  If you make an add function and an edit function that take in a GridView as a paramater.  Something like:

```
protected void Edit(GridView grid)
protected void Add(GridView grid)
```

Then in your button clicked functions you do something like:

```
If (selectedTab = 1) {
       Edit(GridView1);  
}

else if (selectedTab= 2) {
       Edit(GridView2);
}
```

Comment: when i am defining the Methods, shouldn't the code within be generic? where will i define their queries. They are different for each table.

Comment: If each of your tables has different queries you will not want to make the generic functions.  Sorry about that, but your original approach should work as each Grid view does not need a separate button, you just need the `on_clikced` function to execute the correct query for your current `selectedTab`

Comment: I am trying to use 'TabContainer1.ActiveTab.Equals(1){}' Do you reckon it will work? I think it should..

Comment: ok using this one: if(TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 1){ //second tab
}
 Thanks for your help :)